# gitignore everything except few files in directory is not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I have many json files in folder log_files/backend_logs I want to ignore all files except file named backend_log_template.json

I have used below rule in .gitignore but this is not working for me

```
!log_files/backend_logs/backend_log_template.json
```

Comment: "*…this is not working for me…*" What does it mean? Show us the text output of `git status` please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first exclude everything you want to ignore, then specify what you still want to be tracked:

```
/log_files/backend_logs/*
!/log_files/backend_logs/backend_log_template.json
```